# ClearDB: You need at least one of the super user privileges

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, privileges

I am attempting to import my ClearDB database in Heroku by running the command in the window:

`mysql -u REDACTED -h us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net -p REDACTED < C:/Users/KJA/Downloads/androidchatterdatabase.sql`

After inputting the password, the error appears as:

`ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 27: Access Denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`

Then when seeing what the login is that would require the privileges it notes as:

Is there an alternative host address to use? How can I send my database schema to ClearDB in Heroku and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select a database to work on by passing that as an argument to the command; you don't have privileges for any operation without a database (because that would let you control things at the "server level", not the database level).

Your command needs to be `mysql -u YOURUSERNAME -h us-cdbr-iron-east-02.cleardb.net -p YOURPASSWORD heroku_XXXX < C:/Users/KJA/Downloads/androidchatterdatabase.sql` (or whatever your database name is; I took "heroku_XXXX" from one of your other questions).

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems that the user given by Heroku doesn't have permissions to import a dump into a ClearDB. I've tried: `mysql -u username -h us-xxx.cleardb.net -p heroku_database < dump.sql` but still get the error: `Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation`

Comment: Anyone resolve this issue? Having the same problem at Heroku with ClearDB addon.